# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence for X_train, y_train

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to fit my model on X_train and y_train as below:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features),recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(16))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=72, validation_split=0.1, 
                    verbose=1)
```

where,

```
X_train:  (429591, 5, 11)
X_test:   (47733, 5, 11)
y_train:  (429591,)
y_test:   (47733,)
```

In order to do so, I got the error as `ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).`
To fix this error, I was using below code however, I got another error as `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

`X_train.dtype` is `dtype('O')`

`X_train[0]` looks like

```
array([[3, 30, 4, 399, 696, 60, 212, 0, 303, 981,
        list([-2.1380737, 1.9840922, -0.21595824, 1.7971923, -0.49482924])],
       [3, 30, 4, 399, 696, 60, 212, 0, 303, 981,
        list([-2.1380737, 1.9840922, -0.21595824, 1.7971923, -0.49482924])],
       [3, 30, 4, 399, 696, 60, 212, 0, 303, 981,
        list([-2.1380737, 1.9840922, -0.21595824, 1.7971923, -0.49482924])],
       [3, 30, 4, 399, 696, 60, 212, 0, 303, 981,
        list([-2.1380737, 1.9840922, -0.21595824, 1.7971923, -0.49482924])],
       [3, 30, 4, 399, 696, 60, 212, 0, 303, 981,
        list([-2.1380737, 1.9840922, -0.21595824, 1.7971923, -0.49482924])]],
      dtype=object)
```

where last element of X_train i.e. `list([-2.1380737, 1.9840922, -0.21595824, 1.7971923, -0.49482924])]` is after applying `word2vec`,

and `y_train[0]` contains 0,1.

Can't figure out where am I wrong. Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: What do your inputs represent? It seems that you are trying to give the model two different types of data. If that's the case you may want to look at the Functional API provided by Tensorflow.

Comment: @Marcus The inputs have been label encoded except the last column which contains list